# Smarty modulus extra empty tagset issue

Tags: php, html, smarty

I just spent hours digging of a search, trying to find some info about this problem.
I probably didn't really know what to search for :).
I'm using the Smarty Templating Engine on an ecommerce shop.

On the middle of the first page i have a carousel with products by categories (tabbed) where the issue occured.
The problem takes the form of inserting an empty 'div' with class 'iteration' tagset in the parsed list of products,  at the end and/or at the beggining of the parsed product list.
I think the problem is at the beggining of the foreach loop because
{$smarty.foreach.wrap.index % 3 == 0} =>  0 %3 == 0 the first key of array is 0.

```
<div class="banner-middle">
    <div class="container">
        <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs tab-heading">
            {section name=ca loop=$categorii.id}
            <li class="tab-title {if $i=='1'}active{/if}" role="presentation">
                <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-second" href="#tab_{$i++}">{$categorii.subcategorie[ca]}</a>
            </li>
            {/section}
        </ul>
        <div class="offer-tile tab-content home-carousel">
            {foreach from=$categorii.produse key=k item=v name=block}
                <div id="tab_{$tab_n++}" class="wrap-oferte tab-pane {if $smarty.foreach.block.index == 0}active{/if}" role="tabpanel">
                    <div class="iteration">
                        {foreach from=$v key=a item=b name=wrap}

                        {if $smarty.foreach.wrap.index % 3 == 0}
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_large">
                        <div class="tile-block">
                            <span class="category-tile">{$b.categorie}</span>
                            <div class="tile-product-details">
                                <div class="title-tile">
                                    <a href="{$website}/p/{$b.seo}/{$b.alias}">{$b.titlu}</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image-tile">
                                    <img src="{$b.fotomare}"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buy-tile">
                                    <div class="category-tile">Ambalaj: {$b.gramaj}</div>
                                    <span class="price-left {if $b.pretredus > 0}sale{/if}">{if $b.pretredus > 0} {$b.pretredus} Lei<span class="price-left-redus">{$b.prettotal}</span>{else}{$b.prettotal} Lei{/if}</span>
                                    <a href="{$website}/p/{$b.seo}/{$b.alias}"><i class="icon-carucior"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="iteration">
                        {else}
                        <div class="product_normal">
                            <span class="category-tile">{$b.categorie}</span>
                            <div class="tile-product-details">
                                <div class="title-tile">
                                    <a href="{$website}/p/{$b.seo}/{$b.alias}">{$b.titlu}</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="image-tile">
                                    <img src="{$b.foto}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="buy-tile">
                                    <div class="category-tile">Ambalaj: {$b.gramaj} </div>
                                    <span class="price-left {if $b.pretredus > 0}sale{/if}">{if $b.pretredus > 0} {$b.pretredus} Lei<span class="price-left-redus">{$b.prettotal}</span>{else}{$b.prettotal} Lei{/if}</span>
                                    <a href="{$website}/p/{$b.seo}/{$b.alias}"><i class="icon-carucior"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {if $smarty.foreach.wrap.index is div by $smarty.foreach.wrap.total}
                    </div>
                    {/if}
                    {/if}

                    {/foreach}
                </div>
                </div>
        {/foreach}
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Sory for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Try with $smarty.foreach.wrap.iteration instead of index. Also, check your logic, as it is now your html will easily end up messy, and the template is also difficult to read. Just look at the div "iteration"; Try to rearrange your code to open and close it once as you would do with normal html:

```
 <div class="iteration"><!-- opens the iteration div -->
 {foreach from=$v key=a item=b name=wrap}

 {if $smarty.foreach.wrap.index % 3 == 0}
 </div><!--closes iteration div-->
 <div class="product_large">
 ....
</div>
<div class="iteration"> <!--opens the iteration div again -->
 {else}
...
```

Comment: i added a demo image of my carousel problem

Comment: if i use iteration instead  it gets messy

Comment: if I do not succeed with smarty i will do it in php

Comment: As I said the problem is that your code is messy. If you use index (that starts at 0), it will always create and empty div because you close it with the first condition. If you use iteration (that starts at 1), your code opens and closes divs in the wrong places